# Image is loading double time in React due to useState?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have the following logic that renders an image, the current flow is like the following: if the state is false a spinner shows then when the image loads the spinner disappears.

The core problem here is the state is re-rendering the component causing the image to load again I kind of ran out of options, on how to make an instant switch after the image loads.

It is not a loop but rather the image reloads again even if it is already loaded due to the render caused by `setLoading(true)`.

How to prevent this reloading from happening. The `useEffect` logic is just a simulator for how it might take to load the image, but my real image coms from the icons variable.

```js
export const iconsImg: React.FC<Props> = ({ img: string }) => {

useEffect(() => {
    let newImg = new Image();
    newImg.src = icons[img].props.src;
    newImg.onload = () => {
    setLoading(true);
   };
}, []);


const icons: iconsInterface = {
  a: <img className={classes.imgStyle} alt="a" src={link} />,
  b: <img className={classes.imgStyle} alt="b" src={link} />,
}

const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
return ( 
<React.Fragment>
      {!loading ? (
        <Spinner>
      ) : (
        icons[img]
      )}
</React.Fragment>
)}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Issue

The problem with your last attempt is that you are starting with `loading`  showing the `Spinner`, and you are trying to switch the state after the image is loaded, except that will never be the case, because the image is not mounted in the DOM.

Creating `icons` is not equivalent to creating `img` until it's added in the `return` and mounted into the DOM. And I think it's loading twice cause at some point you added the two of them in the DOM either directly or after `loading` changes.

## Solution

You can simplify your component as below. Notice I removed `icons` and setting `alt` attribute (the one difference between the two) while creating the image. That `setTimeout` is so we see the loader. You can remove it later.

```js
const IconsImg  = ({ img }) => {
 const [loading, setLoding] = React.useState(true);
  return <div >{loading && "Loading..."} <img alt={img} style={{display: loading ? "none" : "block"}} onLoad= {()=> setTimeout(()=> setLoding(false), 1000)} src = "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1657664042206-1a98fa4d153d?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDF8MHxlZGl0b3JpYWwtZmVlZHwxfHx8ZW58MHx8fHw%3D&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60"/></div>;
};

/* The below code is to have a working example here at Stack Overflow */

ReactDOM.render(
  <IconsImg img= "car" />,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`newImg` is a different object from `icons[img]`. When `loading` set
to `true`, browser loads same src this time for `icons[img]`.

You can try this:

First set `display:none` for `icons[img]` if `loading` is `false`;

And:

```
<React.Fragment>
      {loading || (
        <Spinner>
      )}
      icons[img]
</React.Fragment>
```

Then:

```
useEffect(() => {
    icons[img].onload = () => {
      setLoading(true);
    };
}, []);
```

or better:

```
<img className={classes.imgStyle} alt="a" src={link} onload={() => setLoading(true)}/>
```

Comment: the later choice is not triggering the function.. I did this also earlier

Comment: as for the first one onload don't work in JSX elemts !